# PHP: how to enable compression for SplFileObject?

Tags: php, csv, gzip, spl

I'm creating a CSV file using the SPLFile class:

```
$z=new SplFileObject('/tmp/test.csv.gz','w');
$arr=[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[2,4,8],[3,6,9]];
foreach($arr as $f) $z->fputcsv($f);
```

Is there a way to gz-compress my output?

Thanks

gm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). In this case you can use [zlib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php).

```
$z=new SplFileObject('compress.zlib:///tmp/test.csv.gz','w');
$arr=[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[2,4,8],[3,6,9]];
foreach($arr as $f) $z->fputcsv($f);
```